# webview not loaded images

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

it's needs to insert loaded from url html data into webview.

my code

```
 private String getHtmlFromURLJsoup(String url) throws IOException{
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(10000)
                    .get();

            return doc.html();

    }

mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function () { " +
                "setMainContent('" + getHtmlFromURLJsoup(s).replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("'", "") + "');" +
                "})()");
```

Content loaded fine, but images not displayed. How can I load html from url with data (images, styles, scripts...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method from WebView:

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlBody, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

htmlBody - your html downloaded data.

Also try to change String to CharSequence in your method:

```
private CharSequence getHtmlFromURLJsoup(String url) throws IOException{
```

Comment: is a good way, but the reason that I used js to add content to that prescribed in a local file js library. I tried to insert them in HTML using JSOUP but then the functions are not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to implement your own webbrowser?

The html will have links to those other things (images, styles, scripts...) - you need to locate the links in the html and go and fetch them separately - this is what a web browser does.